# How to use Service to receive sms and read sms from inbox and send sms message from inbox to another activity in Android?

Tags: android

I am working an Android project. In this project I am sending some data from android app to webserver.Now I am able to send data from Android client to WebServer using PHP- MySQL perfectly..Now my question is how to make an android app so that I can receive sms and after receiving sms, how to read sms from inbox and then how to send read(retrived) sms message to that app  which is sending data(message) to webserver. I want to receive , read and send to an activity completely in a background.

Comment: You need to implement a Broadcast Receive which receives android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED intent. Search for SMS Receive Broadcast and you will get 100s of pages describing how to do that.

Comment: As Amit shared that you have to listen for android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED braodcast and on that broadcast you will get payload(data). You have to fetch SMS content from payload and send that data to another activity through Intent.